# Being a representative for someone to/against (?) others

Tags: verbs, prepositions

I'm currently writing a job applications for customer-centric jobs and I would like to say that "I'm looking forward to being a representative for the wishes and needs of a community of customers ***to / against - [I absolutely don't know***] developers and product managers". Means: I want to advocate community's needs in discussions with others.

To clarify: 
- The community of the web service has wishes and needs (for example a new button or a new feature)
- I'm the support guy between the community and the developers who are developing the web service 
- Meaning: It is my job to communicate the community's wish for a new button to the developers. This is necessary because sometimes developers don't understand why a certain feature is needed so i have to act as a facilitator to make that clear.

All this is happening in one company: The company is offering one web service that has one community that is using this service, which engineered by a bunch of developers.

Do you know what I mean? Could you please give me a hint for the missing word? 
Thanks in advance!
Florian

Comment: Have you left out ***being*** after *"I'm looking forward to"*? But what exactly is supposed to be having this relationship with "developers and product managers"? Is it "a representative"? Or "the wishes and needs"? Or "a community of customers". I think the whole sentence is wooly, and would do better with a complete rewrite. I don't think there's a suitable preposition that will fix things.

Comment: Thanks for reply! 
It's me! :D I'm supposed to have this relationship with the developers :) So I will communicate the wishes and needs of the community to the developers.
I added a clarification to the orignial post to highlight this.

Comment: @ Cube42: That very useful edit is the reason I'm upvoting the question. It might be simpler to address what looks like your *specific* issue if we reduce the verbiage *preceding* the point where your problematic word (preposition?) needs to go. *"I look forward to representing the user community [**???**] the developers"*. Of course, if all you really want is someone to suggest a totally different way of putting the point across, that's a different matter (which may in any case be *writing advice* or *proofreading*).

Answer (score 1):

Not being sure exactly what you are trying to say, I'll take a guess and reword your verbiage.

> "I'm looking forward to representing _____________ [name of company] in meeting the wishes and needs of a community of customers, including developers and product managers".

Or,

> "I'm looking forward to advocating [thanks to andy256, above] for the needs of a community of customers, developers, and product managers."

Or, you could use your word *TO*, indicating that TO the customers you are their representative, advocate, or intercessor on behalf of the company that employs you.

> "I'm looking forward to being an advocate to a community of customers, developers, and product managers on behalf of _______________ [name of company]."

Or,

> "I'm looking forward to being ______________ [possessive of the company name, as in XYZ Corporation's] representative to a diverse community of customers, developers, and product managers."

The word diverse might be a good idea, if indeed the community of customers includes a diverse group of people.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, rhetorician!
The problem with your three options is that they don't contain my position as a middle man / facilitator between the community and the developers. 
To say it in another way: It is my role to translate the wishes and needs of the community in such a way that the developers are able to understand what the community wants and needs.

So I'm looking for the preposition that is describing the second part of this relation. I will try to use "in behalf" to formulate a new version.

Answer (score 0):

**Advocate**

> a person who argues for or supports a cause or policy
>
> a person who works for a cause or group
>
> a person who argues for the cause of another person in a court of law

-- [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/advocate)